# Get local variables of previous scope

Tags: ruby, scope, ruby-1.9.3

I am making a Ruby REPL to be used inside an application. I made code:

```
a = 1
b = 2
currentScope = []
Kernel.local_variables.each do |var|
    currentScope << [var,Kernel.eval(var.to_s)]
end
launchREPL(currentScope)
```

Inside the REPL, I can execute the following code:

```
@a     #=>1
@a+@b  #=>3
```

Ideally I wouldn't have to write the four lines of code before I launch the REPL, and instead I would like to run them inside the `launchREPL` function. However this would require access to the previous scope from inside the `launchREPL` function.

---

#### Test1

Most notably I tried:

```
launchREPL(Kernel)
```

When I do the following:

```
def launchREPL(scope)
    F = 0
    puts scope.local_variables # => [:F]
end
```

it is apparent that this method is not valid.

#### Test2

```
launchREPL(Kernel.binding)

def launchREPL(scope)
    Kernel.binding.local_variables #= Error: private method 'local_variables' called for #<Binding>
end
```

Is there any way to do what I'm trying to do?

---

*Edit: P.S. This is currently the code inside launchREPL:*

```
def launchREPL(scope=nil,winName="Ruby REPL")
    # ICM RB file Begin:
    puts "\"Starting REPL...\""
    __b = binding   #Evaluating in a binding, keeps track of local variables
    __s = ""


    ###############################################################################
    # SEND INSTANCE VARIABLES TO REPL
    ###############################################################################
    #
    #How to prepare scope
    #   currentScope = []
    #   Kernel.local_variables.each do |var|
    #       currentScope << [var,Kernel.eval(var.to_s)]
    #   end
    #   launchREPL(currentScope)

    if scope != nil
        scope.each do |varDef|
            __b.instance_variable_set "@#{varDef[0].to_s}" , varDef[1]
            __b.eval("@#{varDef[0].to_s} = __b.instance_variable_get(:@#{varDef[0].to_s})")
        end
    end

    # to get instance variables: __b.instance_variable_get(__b.instance_variables[0])
    # or better:                 __b.instance_variable_get(:@pipe1)
    #
    ###############################################################################

    bStartup = true
    while bStartup || __s != ""
        # If startup required skip evaluation step
        if !bStartup

            #Evaluate command
            begin
                __ret = __s + "\n>" + __b.eval(__s).to_s
            rescue 
                __ret = __s + "\n> Error: " + $!.to_s
            end
            puts __ret
        else
            #REPL is already running
            bStartup = false
        end

        #Read user input & print previous output
        __s = WSApplication.input_box(__ret,winName,"")
        __s == nil ? __s = "" : nil
    end
end
```

Comment: I have posted the corrected version of `launchREPL` that works as another answer. I still **do not advise** to use it. This implementation is **vulnerable** and possibly **not robust**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won’t fit the comment, so I would post it as an answer.

```
def launchREPL(scope = nil, winName = "Ruby REPL")
  puts '"Starting REPL..."'

  scope.eval('local_variables').each do |var|
    instance_variable_set "@#{var}", scope.eval(var.to_s)
  end if scope

  s = ""
  loop do
    ret = begin
            "#{s}\n> #{eval(s)}"
          rescue => e
            "#{s}\n> Error: #{e.message}"
          end
    puts ret
    # s = WSApplication.input_box(ret, winName, "")
    # break if s.empty?
    s = "100 * @a" # remove this line and uncomment 2 above
  end
end

a = 42
launchREPL(binding)
```

This is how your function should be written (I have just make it looking as ruby code.) The above works (currently it has no `break` at all, but you can see as it’s calculating `4200` infinitely.)

Comment: Thanks Mudasobwa. This works great! I understand what you mean by 'It is not robust', but honestly, having a ruby REPL is better than not having one at all, when it comes to debugging code. I'll have to make a few modifications though as currently the variables are not stored. (That was why I used the binding __b)

Comment: Also `scope = nil` should also be replaced with `scope = binding`

Comment: Ruby comes with [`irb`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/irb/rdoc/IRB.html) bundled and there is great [`pry`](http://pryrepl.org/) FWIW. When I was saying you are doing it wrong, I meant that reinventing a wheel when there are lasers all around and we are conquering Mars is outrageous.

Comment: Yeah, sadly there isn't a shell i can use... That's literally why I'm making my own. I can't even write to html to make a nice interface... I've tried setting up events, like keyboard events, but you can't even do stuff like that. Once the interpreter finishes reading the script, it quits the process. The company has got an external application which can run ruby applications outside of the UI (which would allow me to use irb), however, I would also have to spend [£8666](http://www.innovyze.com/products/infoworks_icm/#icmexchange) for it... So for now, this is good enough.

Answer (score 3):

Although what you are trying to achieve is unclear and there are definitely many ways to do it properly, *every* ruby method might be called with [`Object#send`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-send) approach:

```
def launchREPL(scope)
  scope.send :local_variables #⇒ here you go
end

a = 42
launchREPL(binding).include?(:a)
#⇒ true
```

---

*Sidenote:* this is how your “4 lines” are usually written in ruby:

```
local_variables.map { |var| [var, eval(var.to_s)] }
```

And this is how they *should be written* (note [`Binding#local_variable_get`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Binding.html#method-i-local_variable_get)):

```
local_variables.map { |var| [var, binding.local_variable_get(var)] }
```

---

The summing up:

```
def launchREPL(scope)
  vars = scope.send(:local_variables).map do |var|
           [var, scope.local_variable_get(var)]
         end
  # some other code
end
a = 42
launchREPL(binding).to_h[:a]
#⇒ 42
```

Comment: Hmm you see I tried something akin to this (not as fancy though ofc...) before however I get the error `undefined method 'local_variable_get' for '#<Binding...>'` @ line `[var, scope.local_variable_get(var)]`. If it wasn't clear, I wanted to be able to access `a` in your last example, from inside the launchREPL function.

Comment: It’s still isn’t clear. `scope.local_variable_get(var)` (third line in my last example) does exactly that: it **accesses the local variable from inside the `launchREPL` function**.

Comment: If I run your last piece of code in 'summing up' I get an error: class = NoMethodError; message = undefined method `local_variable_get' for #<Binding:0x0000002ed2b918>; U:/Macros/9_Ruby/REPL/TestREPL - Lib.rb:3:in `block in launchREPL';U:/Macros/9_Ruby/REPL/TestREPL - Lib.rb:2:in `map';U:/Macros/9_Ruby/REPL/TestREPL - Lib.rb:2:in `launchREPL';U:/Macros/9_Ruby/REPL/TestREPL - Lib.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'

Comment: What ruby version do you use? `0.0.1`?

Comment: Apparently ruby 1.9.3. But that's the choice of the developers of the software we use, not mine sadly...

Comment: Then I believe you got stuck to `eval`, sorry for suggesting that.

Comment: No problem, I should probably write that in the title. Thanks for the input regardless :)

Comment: `scope.send(:local_variables).map { |var| [var, eval(var.to_s)] }` must be the working solution for `1.9.3`.

Comment: if I insert `puts scope.send(:local_variables).map { |var| [var, eval(var.to_s)] }` into launch REPL and then run `a = 42;\n launchREPL(binding)` it returns  `scope` and  `#<Binding:0x0000001316b620>`. How would I return `a`?

Comment: `puts` prints out the mapped value, namely, all the bindings. I have no idea why would you decide to `puts` there. Once again: you are doing it wrong, especially taking into account the questions arised. It’s dangerous, there are many pitfalls and in general one should not use this technique. It’s plain wrong way. Also, it’s unclear _where_ would you want to _return a_.

Comment: If it wasn't clear I am fairly new to ruby. That's why I used `puts` there... I'm curious though, what would be the better way to do this? Given that this is 'the plain wrong way'. I would love a better way to debug code, but a REPL is the best I can think of.

Comment: This is great. Quick question — why favor `Binding#local_variable_get` over `eval`?

Comment: @RyanLue Because sooner or later you’ll execute it on user input and lose all your money. `Binding` is safe, `eval` might remove files from your filesystem.